# Upload Image Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

why my method and taskSnapshot doesn't work ?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrhFo.png]

and here's my POJO

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAx9H.png]

Answer (score 0):

Add other 4 parameters using coma `,`

Answer (score 0):

As declared in your **UserInformation** you need to put all parameter to create the object.

Try something like that :

```
String judul = "";
String isi = "";
String penulis = "";
String kat = "";
String url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString;

UserInformation userInformation = UserInformation(judul , isi, penulis, kat, url)
```